# How can i create listbox on Flutter like on picture?

Tags: flutter

i am doing  an app for an order app i need  to create boxes like on picture how can i do that?,
i tried many things but could not do that and i added a picture below what i want to do  how can i create those boxes if you have any suggestions please let me know

[this is image which is i included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qfj9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
      child: ListTile(
      title: Row(children: [
           Expanded(
              child: Text("Onion 3 Cal", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
           Expanded(child: Text("-", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
           Expanded(child: Text("Extra", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
           Expanded(child: Text("+", textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
             ]),
      leading: Icon(Icons.image)))
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Attach the code you are working on. Also note you might have to change the values according to your need. The above snippet is just a template to help you.